# Why can't I call a method on the prototype?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype, iife

I am trying to create a JavaScript object constructor within a closure, and then return the constructor so that I can create this object without any conflicts with other JS libraries.

Consider this code:

```javascript
Test = (function(){

    var T = function(){
        this.x = 0;
    }

    T.prototype.doSomething = function(){
        this.x = 10;
    }

    return T;

});
var test = new Test();
test.doSomething(); 
alert(test.x);
```

Why is it that `test.doSomething()` is not a function, when I have defined it in the prototype?

Comment: You need to create a new instance with `new`: `new Test()`

Comment: I apologise, but that third line from the bottom is supposed to say 
"var test = new Test();" - hence the 'new' keyword that is supposed to attach the prototype.

Comment: This should be closed as a simple typo. It's just a failed attempt at an IIFE, adding `()` to the end of the outer function expression fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not creating an instance of the right function! If you look at `Test`:

```
var Test = (function() {
  //...
  return T;
});
```

Here, you're assigning `Test` to *function that returns `T`*, not `T` itself! That's why you can't call a method on the prototype of `T`. Instead, use an IIFE:

```
var Test = (function() {

})(); //Important!
```

This will assign `T`'s reference to `Test`. Then create a new instance:

```
new Test();
```

Comment: Oh my gosh! I have been a fool! Thank you so much! I have actually been stuck on this for hours!

Comment: @eddykent No problem!